# "Large" S3 Images Not Able to Load in PHP

Tags: php, appfog

I'm trying to use WordPress on the AppFog PaaS system. Unfortunately, AppFog doesn't have persistent storage so all content outside of the database needs to be stored on some external system (like S3). I'm successfully using a plugin which pushes all my WordPress media out to S3, but am having problems loading some of the images.

To investigate, I deployed the following script:

```
// get the image name from the query string 
// and make sure it's not trying to probe your file system 
if (isset($_GET['pic'])) { 
    $pic = $_GET['pic'];

    // get the filename extension 
    $ext = substr($pic, -3);

    // set the MIME type 
    switch ($ext) { 
        case 'jpg': 
            $mime = 'image/jpeg';
            break;
        case 'gif': 
            $mime = 'image/gif';
            break;
        case 'png': 
            $mime = 'image/png';
            break;
        default: 
            $mime = false;
     }
     // if a valid MIME type exists, display the image 
    // by sending appropriate headers and streaming the file 
    if ($mime) { 
        header('Content-type: '.$mime);
        header('Content-length: '.filesize($pic));
        $file = fopen($pic, 'rb');
        if ($file) { 
            fpassthru($file);
            exit;
         }

     }
 }

 ?>
```

Which allows me to directly test my ability to read and write an image in PHP. This proxy script works perfectly for images under around 10KB -- i.e. when I open the script in a browser pointing it at some "small" image file in my S3 bucket, I'm able to see it.

However, when I attempt to load a "large" file (anything over 10KB), I get an error. In Firefox, that's:

```
The image “http://myssite.com/iproxy.php?pic=http://aws.amazon.com%2Fmybucket%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F01%2Fmylargeimage.png” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.
```

I've been wrestling with this for hours and can't seem to figure anything out. I've tried changing the `output_buffering` to a larger value but that hasn't helped.

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you need this script? You should be able to point users to your S3 resources directly, rather than proxying it.

Comment: Right, the WP theme I'm using does some image resizing, so it actually loads and processes the images from the external URL before serving them.

Comment: Avoid those. Store your images at the needed sizes and your site will perform much better.

Comment: Sure. Ultimately, I'd like to save each resized image back to S3 so that I don't have to recompute them on each request. But in order to do the initial resizing of 100+ images, I'd like to handle that automatically in PHP.